# How to hint an asynchronous operation with a JavaScript promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

For learning purposes, I want to show how promises can help solving time dependencies of database operations in JavaScript.

So, I want to show that:

```
db.find(14);
```

actually consumes time behind the scenes.

How could I illustrate this time dependency and a possible solution that a Promises provides?

What I have so far is this:

```
  // data store operation take time
  function _findByUsername(username) {
    var user = _.findWhere(Users, {username: username});
    if (!user) {
      Promise.reject(new Error("User not found."));
    }
    return Promise.resolve(user);
  }
```

Comment: Where does `db.find` come in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it useful to always return a promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473728/is-it-useful-to-always-return-a-promise)

Comment: Related reading: http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony

Comment: the `db.find()` should be an Async operation, e.g. like https://github.com/mulderp/echojs/blob/master/api/users.js#L109-L111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option might be to use the [delay](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisedelaydynamic-value-int-ms---promise) function of Bluebird and add a comment as follows:

```
findByUsername(username) { 
   /* simulates the behavior of a database operation */
   return Promise.delay(10).thenReturn(_.findWhere(Users, {username: username}))
 }
```

Comment: Why would you deliberately slow your code down? Is this just for mocking?

Comment: yes. By adding a delay, one could simulate the influence of time at higher abstraction levels, in worst case, even the influence of time-outs. what do you think? the point here is to leave a database connection out, but understand influence of time while promise paths are evaluated.

Comment: I think the only correct way to determine the response times is to use a database and profile it. Everything other than profiling isn't very useful.