# How to use catch and finally with when.map

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, when-js

I want to use the `when.map` function to process some data.
After the data is processed I need to do some cleanup (e.g. release the currently used database connection back to the connection pool).

The problem with my approach using `catch` and `finally`  is that `finally` is called when the first `reject` occurs, and while other *mappings* are still in progress.

So how can I wait until all of the *mapping* promises are finished, so that it is possible to do a save cleanup.

```
  require('when/monitor/console');
  var when = require('when');

  function testMapper(value) {
    console.log('testMapper called with: '+value);
    return when.promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('reject: '+value);
        reject(new Error('error: '+value));
      },100*value);
    });
  }

  when.map([1,2,3,4],testMapper)
  .then(function() {
    console.log('finished')
  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  })
  .finally(function() {
    console.log('finally')
  });
```

**Output**

```
 testMapper called with: 1
 testMapper called with: 2
 testMapper called with: 3
 testMapper called with: 4
 reject: 1
 [Error: error: 1]
 finally
 reject: 2
 [promises] Unhandled rejections: 1
 Error: error: 2
     at null._onTimeout (index.js:9:14)

 reject: 3
 [promises] Unhandled rejections: 2
 Error: error: 2
     at null._onTimeout (index.js:9:14)

 Error: error: 3
     at null._onTimeout (index.js:9:14)

 reject: 4
 [promises] Unhandled rejections: 3
 Error: error: 2
     at null._onTimeout (index.js:9:14)

 Error: error: 3
     at null._onTimeout (index.js:9:14)

 Error: error: 4
     at null._onTimeout (index.js:9:14)
```

**Environmentinformation:**

- whenjs: v3.1.0
- node: v0.10.26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to go with `when.settle`, settle returns all promises when they resolve, not when they fulfill so you can manually check which one did well and which one did not.

```
var arrayOfPromises = array.map(testMapper);
when.settle(arrayOfPromises).then(function(descriptors){
     descriptors.forEach(function(d){
         if(d.state === "rejected"){
             // do cleanup for that promise, you can access its rejection reason here
             // and do any cleanup you want
         } else{
            // successful results accessed here
            console.log("Successful!", d.value);
         }
     })
});
```

---

Note:

This is actually not a small problem. When I say not a small problem, what I mean is that it's a huge problem that's really hard to solve correctly. There are multiple implied behaviors here and edge cases.

Consider reading [this somewhat lengthy discussion](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/65). 
If you're willing to consider - Bluebird has an experimental `promise-using` branch that allows specifying disposers, which would let you do this rather easily.

You would be able to do:

```
using(pool.getConnectionAsync().disposer("close"), function(connection) {
   return connection.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
}).then(function(rows) {
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Or in the multiple resource case:

```
var a = Promise.cast(externalPromiseApi.getResource1()).disposer("close");
var b = Promise.cast(externalPromiseApi.getResource2()).disposer("close");
using(a, b, function(resource1, resource2) {
    // once the promise returned here is resolved, we have a deterministic guarantee that 
    // all the resources used here have been closed.
})
```

Comment: I'll take a closer look at `settle`. But it is definitely not a behavior that I would have expected, especially as it is compared with the classical `try - catch - finally` block in the docs. Every time I think that I understood everything about _promise_ then have to find out that there are even more stumbling blocks :D.

Comment: @t.niese the problem isn't similar to try/catch/finally in general. The problem is resource acquisition in general, resource acquisition is a huge issue in programming. For example, see copying a file in Java with try/catch/finally http://stackoverflow.com/a/909376/1348195 - with `try-resource` in Java, you could do `try(resource1,resource2){ /* resources get disposed if fail here */}`. The goal of `Promise.using` is to give you the same level of ease of use only with asynchronous resource acquisitions and operations. Not an easy task.

Comment: For an example of a problem - here is Eric Lippert's answer to a conceptual issue we've faced when discussing `Promise.using` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21123756/1348195 . We solved this particular problem by not allowing disposers to throw.

Comment: I understand the problem. I think I had the wrong expectations while reading the docs and because of that I have seen the operations like `when.map`, `when.join`, `when.all`, ... as somehow _atomic_, that the only will `reject` if none of the _promieses_ passed to them are in a `pending` state anymore, like it is for the `resolve`. While I could understand that the `catch` may be called immediately, I still would expect that `finally` should wait until all of the promises are not in `pending` state anymore. Anyway thx for the time you spend answering the question.

Comment: @t.niese For what it's worth I feel your pain. I think the using construct is definitely the way to go. Glad I could help you with the issue.

Comment: I solve my problem for now, by writing a _settle.map_ out of your answer. And now have time to look into `bluebird`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of *Benjamin Gruenbaum* I create a replacement of `when.map` that uses settle internally, and will trigger the `cache` and `finally` when all promises of the `map` have been handled.

```
  var settle = {};
  var arrayMap = Array.prototype.map;

  settle.map = function(array, f) {

    var arrayOfPromises = arrayMap.call(array,function(x) {
      return when.resolve(x).then(f);
    });

    return when.settle(arrayOfPromises)
    .then(function(descriptors) {
      var result = [];

      descriptors.forEach(function(descriptor) {
        if( descriptor.state === 'rejected') {
          throw descriptor.reason;
        }

        result.push(descriptor.value);
      });

      return result;
    });
  };
```

When I now replace `when.map` with `settle.map` in my original code, then the output/execution order is as I require it:

```
 testMapper called with: 1
 testMapper called with: 2
 testMapper called with: 3
 testMapper called with: 4
 reject: 1
 reject: 2
 reject: 3
 reject: 4
 [Error: error: 1]
 finally
```