# Shortest way to iterate over non-list?

Tags: java, java-8

Suppose I have 3 Scanner instances which I want to close.

I could do

```
sc.close()
```

for each of the Scanners.

Or I could do something like

```
for (Scanner sc: new Scanner[]{sc1,sc2,sc3}) {
    sc.close();
}
```

Is there any shorter way of doing this with Java 8?

Something similar to?

```
{sc1,sc2,sc3}.forEach((sc) -> sc.close());
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390463/java-8-stream-and-operation-on-arrays

Comment: To answer the general question: `Stream.of(sc1, sc2, sc3).forEach(Scanner::close);`, but for this specific case [listen to Gerald Mücke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37023624/2711488)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Since Java 7 you should use try-with-resources

```
try(Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(""); 
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(""); 
    Scanner sc3 = new Scanner("")){

}
//all scanners get closed implicitly
```

So you don't need any code at all.

The problem with all for-each or stream constructs is, that - theoretically - if the first `close()` fails with an exception on invoking the underlying source's `close()` method, the following scanners won't get closed. The `Scanner.close()` implementation catches any IOException, but no  other exception that may occur.

The try-with-resources construct deals with that, the loops don't.

---

**EDIT**: While your question targeted at a more general approach, the above solution was a response to your particular problem: to deal with `AutoCloseable` resources, which should in any case be used with the *try-with-resources* construct, requiring no special treatment of the close method at all (= shortest solution to your particular problem).

Regarding the more general question about dealing with arbitrary items (which are no resources), Java has at least two options:

Creating a List from an Array/Varargs and iterate over it

```
for(YourItemType item : Arrays.asList(your,items,here)) {
  //do something
}
```

Creating a Stream from an Array/Varargs and apply functions to it

```
Stream.of(your,items,here).forEach(item -> { doSomething});
```

Of course the "doSomething" can be replaced with a method reference

```
Stream.of(your,items,here).forEach(this::myMethod);
...
void myMethod(YourItemType item){
  //doSomething
}
```

The problem with that approach is, that checked exception have to be dealt with explicitly in lambda expressions. Lets take the above example and let `myMethod` throw a checked exception

```
void myMethod(YourItemType item) throws Exception
```

in that case your stream statement would have to look like

```
Stream.of(your,items,here).forEach(item -> {
  try {
    myMethod(item);
  } catch (Exception e){
    //omit or throw new RuntimeException(e);
  };
```

This doesn't look that nice. But we could put the lambda body in a separate method

```
void myMethodQuietly(YourItemType item) {
  try {
    myMethod(item);
  }catch(Exception e){
    //omit or throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}

Stream.of(your,items,here).forEach(this::myMethodQuietly);
```

This approach may be of interest to your particular resource problem. We can put all this into a `CompositeAutoCloseable` that takes resources created outside the class that all should be closed safely on invocation of `close()`

```
public class CompositeAutoCloseable implements AutoCloseable {

  private List<Closeable> resources;

  public CompositeAutoCloseable(Closeable... resources) {
    this.resources = Arrays.asList(resources);
    //you could use a stream here too
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
      this.resources.stream().forEach(this::closeQuietly);
  }

  void closeQuietly(Closeable res) {
    if(res == null)  {
        return;
    }
    try {
        res.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        //omit
    }
  } 
}
```

And once you have such a helper class, you can use it again with try-with-resources.

```
try(CompositeAutoCloseable cac = new CompositeAutoCloseable(sc1,sc2,sc3)) {
  //do something
}
```

I leave it up to you to decide if this makes sense compared to the inital solution ;)

Comment: This answer seems to make the most sense to me. Leveraging `AutoCloseable`s instead of hard-streaming to explicitly close the `Scanner`s seems the most natural solution.

Comment: Note that try-with-resource still isn't really 100% safe. Here is a simple example from C# of where this might be problematic with the corresponding construct: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21123756/1348195

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: that post uses a lot of C# constructs that don’t exist in Java. Generally, it’s not the responsibility of the code *using* `Scanner` to fix potential bugs in the constructor of the class `Scanner`. Sure, it isn’t “100% safe”, but nothing is. How do you protect against someone pulling the plug?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  Of course you want to use `try` when you can, but that's not always an option.  For example, when your class creates three `Scanner` instances in its constructor, and closes them in its own `close()` method.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: even then, you are better off using the `try` construct to ensure that all three are closed safely: `try(Scanner toClose1=sc1; Scanner toClose2=sc2) { sc3.close(); }`

Comment: When I asked the question I did want a more general solution as @Holger commented with but your solution did improve my code a lot. I feel that an example of the `Stream.of` variant would help to answer the question I originally had which is reflected in the title. Even though this answer seems to be most fitting, to the code example given, I originally sought the shortest way.

Answer (score 3):

If instantiation is separated from disposal, use Guava's [com.google.common.io.Closer](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closer.html).

Answer (score -1):

Although there is sometimes a correlation between the length of the code and its quality that is not a good criterion to use to choose code.

I would probably use varargs and do it something like:

```
private void closeScanner(Scanner... scanners) {
    // Faff around with Java 8 in here if you like.
    for (Scanner s : scanners) {
        s.close();
    }
}

    // Some code.
    closeScanner(s, t, u);
```

Comment: Exception safety fail

Comment: @basilevs - Scanner.close does not throw exceptions.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: well, it throws only unchecked exceptions.

Comment: @SteveJessop - Then they will be caught elsewhere no? Still not clear how this is an exception safety fail.

Comment: If the first call to `close()` does throw an exception, then regardless of whether it's caught elsewhere, the second and third calls won't even be attempted. If you want resource cleanup to be attempted even following a failure, but it isn't attempted, that's what Basilevs means by an "exception safety fail" and that's what try-with-resources is designed to help do.